# I can't ssh to a server on my laptop, but can log in on my colleague's computer

Tags: ssh, ping

In my office network, recently I started being not able to connect the server in the same office with my account, and the error message is:

```
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Connection refused
```

The '22' port is enabled on the server, and I only got this problem very recently. It has been fine in the past. I can still occasionally successfully logged in, but the chances are becoming more and more slim.

However, on my colleague's computer, I can still use my account to log in (ssh). We both use Mac laptop.

What might be the reason? My colleague also had a very few times to encounter the problem, but his situation is much better. My situation is the worst. Now I can barely log into the server in the server.

What may cause this?  The server is a ubuntu machine, and I am using Mac.

When I ping that machine:
seq=3 ttl=64 time=116.854 ms

```
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=132.539 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=14.089 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=178.914 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=203.784 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=287.408 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=311.417 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=67.460 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=77.491 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=114.773 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=132.176 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=155.927 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=172.302 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=194.840 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=282.515 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=301.924 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=19 ttl=64 time=323.514 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=20 ttl=64 time=67.834 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=21 ttl=64 time=89.552 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 22
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=23 ttl=64 time=405.122 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=24 ttl=64 time=160.683 ms
```

The 'time' is too big and that's causing the problem. Why is that?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the server. Have you reviewed any log files or done any other troubleshooting? Who manages the server?

Comment: @Appleoddity I checked the /var/log/auth.log, but didn't find any login attempts for me.

Comment: Are you both on the same wifi/wired network?

Comment: Yes. it is. ssh: connect to host 10.1.10.189 port 22: Connection refused